Не удалось получить доступ к «TOSHIBA EXT»
Имею внешний жесткий диск и столкнулся с проблемой.
При попытке открыть диск через Файлы, выдаёт ошибку 
Не удалось получитьдоступ к «TOSHIBA EXT»
Error mounting/dev/sdb1 at/run/media/user/
TOSHIBA EXT: wrong fs type, bad option, bad
superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or
helper program, or other error

Использую Manjaro Linux 
До этого всё работало исправно.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Вы смогли перевести и понять сообщение об ошибке? "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"
